# reference request about sobolev space and BV space

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces, bounded-variation

I am studying Sobolev Space and BV space by using Leoni's and Evans & Gariepy's book. I was wondering that where can I find some explicit example and some computational question of those space. A question like compute whether
$$ u(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)$$
is BV, Sobolev, or AC.

I know Leoni's book has some, but I am looking for more.(Especially in 1-D)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can generalize your example to $x^a \sin (1/x^b)$.

Comment: Yes I know. I just wondering is there more? Like other kind of functions?